# Distinct event types on same collection - MongoDB and .NET Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I want to use MongoDB to store domain events in a system written with .NET Core and C#.

I've googled a little about this, and it seems it is a common practice to have *a single* collection called `events` and simply store all events there. I've also seem people to create one field `type` to distinguish events. An example of this is Slide 66 of [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/dbellettini/cqrs-and-event-sourcing-with-mongodb-and-php).

So if I wanted to save one `UserCreated` event I would add it with type `user-created`, and so forth.

Now I'm in doubt with respect to the mapping when it comes to using .NET Core.

Two distinct events will in general have different schema, so I think that the automatic mapping would do no good. Of course I could use the option of ignoring extra elements. But it may be the case that two events have subsets of properties which are equal, for example, all of them will have a `OccurredOn` DateTime. I think this could be an issue.

My idea was to query the field `type`. Something like:

```
colection.Find(BsonDocument.Parse("{type: user-created}"))
```

But I don't know if that is the best option, or if there is a way to set up a mapping so that the MongoDrive knows that whenever we try to get an instance of `UserCreated` it should look just for that type, and when we try to insert, it should create the correct `type` field.

In that case: given that we save distinct event types to the same collection, what is the correct approach to map this into the right C# event objects?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a container like this one.

```cs
public class DomainEventContainer
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string EventData { get; set; }
}
```

And then based on the value of DomainEventContainer.Type, you could deserialize EventData into your desired type.